# how to fix my null ResponseEntity response in junit Mock test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, resttemplate

I am trying to test a RestTemplate exchange with a response entity in a controller from a rest Service in another application. My Junit test is coming back with a null ResponseEntity. I have tried a couple ways with no luck. First tried using mockito to mock response methods (when...then). Second tried with Exchange matchers. I also tried to mix the two with no luck. Any help would be great. Here is my Controller response I am creating:

```
ResponseEntity<RestResult<List<SiteMessage>>> response = rest.exchange(getAllMessagesUrl, HttpMethod.GET,
    HttpEntity.EMPTY, new ParameterizedTypeReference<RestResult<List<SiteMessage>>>() {
});
```

Here is my Junit Test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MessageControllerTests {

    @InjectMocks
    MessageController messageController;

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    SiteMessageService serviceMock;

    @Mock
    ResponseEntity<RestResult<List<SiteMessage>>> response;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(messageController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testListPage() throws Exception {

        RestResult<List<SiteMessage>> result = new RestResult<>();

        result.setMessage("success");

        SiteMessage message1 = new SiteMessage();
        SiteMessage message2 = new SiteMessage();

        message1.setId("ldsf030j2ldjs");

        message2.setId("ldsf0432234s");


        List<SiteMessage> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        messageList.add(message1);
        messageList.add(message2);

        result.setResults(messageList);

        when(response.getBody()).thenReturn(result);

        when(response.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

        when(restTemplate.exchange(
            Matchers.any(URI.class),
            Matchers.eq(HttpMethod.GET),
            Matchers.any(),
            Matchers.<ParameterizedTypeReference<RestResult<List<SiteMessage>>>>any())
        ).thenReturn(response);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/message/list")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("message/list"));
    }

}
```

I am trying to return a response with a body containing a RestResult object, which has a list of messages and a message

Comment: where are you getting null.  which line?

Comment: @pvpkiran not a line represented, but my whole "response" variable is coming back null from the first block of code above when running the unit test

Comment: Do you want to write unit test or integration test ?

Comment: @haticeSigirci unit test

Comment: Could you add your class which you want to test to clarify that what the class can do?